# How to have Chromium auto login to web page in kiosk mode?

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromium, kiosk, autologin

I've browsed various resources but I seem to be unable to get this to work on a Raspi that is supposed to be used for digital signage. Chromium does start up in kiosk mode, loads the webpage and autofills the saved credentials but I still need to click on 'sign in' on this button:

`<button name="button" type="submit">Sign in</button>`

I can't do that however, since there will be no keyboard/mouse attached when the Raspi is eventually installed in the store. How can I automate the click? I've try the Chrome extension [Auto Login](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-login/kjdgohfkopafhjmmlbojhaabfpndllgk?hl=en) but it does not work in kiosk mode.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the starting page with an extra param like '?kiosk=1', then have a javascript snippet onload check for this param and auto-submit the form after 'n' seconds to account for any delays in filling the password.

```html
<body onload='init()'>
<form id="login-form">...</form>
<script>
function init() {
  const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  if (params.has('kiosk')) { //check if ?kiosk is defined in URL
    setTimeout(
      function () { document.getElementById("login-form").submit(); },
      1000
    );
  }
}
</script>
</body>
```